# Graphical interfaces to search for files?

Tags: applications, files, search

What graphical interfaces exist to assist the user in searching for files?

Comment: This is quite opinion based, and there will be no correct answer. Consider [edit]ing your question to be more asking "what tools are there?" rather than "what do you use?"

Comment: I don't think this needs closing, I've suggested an edit that should do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because there are many, many ways to search for files. I suggest restricting the question in one or more aspects such as searches that don't require an index; command line or GUI; specific kinds of searches (by file name, content, etc.); things that can be done without installing extra software; etc.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your suggestion. I limited my edit to only graphical interfaces. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I installed gnome-search-tool:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool
```

Create `find.contract` in `/usr/share/contractor` and add to the entry:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Search Here
Description=Find files
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=gnome-search-tool --path=%f %U
```

After these steps, I can use advanced search in any folder.

[image: contractor]
[image: search tool]

Comment: This is _extremely_ useful.

Comment: What is the advantage of this over just using `Ctrl + f` in `Files`?

Comment: More options. For Example "Contains the text". Also, I use Luna :)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the actual tool in action?

Comment: @RolandiXor updated.

Comment: This should be installed by default on elementary.

Comment: Is there a way to enable this as a keyboard shortcut for the current folder, like `Ctrl+Shift+F`? I like to view my folders in "details" mode, so switching to "thumbnails" mode is annoying to do "Search Here".

Comment: gnome-search-tool is not available on my install (elementary os 5.1.4)

Answer (score 24):

### The default file manager **Pantheon Files has a search option**:

- Open the folder you need to search in
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and the path bar will show a search glass icon.

  *If you just open a folder and start typing your search, the search glass icon appears anyway, but then the search will NOT go within the sub-folders*
- Just type there your search: a list of findings is immediately displayed
- Don't touch anything!
- Wait for it to finish without clicking anywhere on the desktop, or the search (and the list of findings) will close if the path-bar (now search bar) loses focus.

[image]

---

### Other solutions:

### Nautilus

What I don't like about Pantheon Files' search is that the search results are [not displayed in a proper window](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/122/170), just a list that is closed when it loses focus.

So, one may use of course other file managers that have a search function, like Nautilus. (I use Nautilus, because it is installed automatically with some applications that I need.) I see no disadvantage in having Nautilus alongside Pantheon Files.

### Catfish

Or you may use other popular search tools like `catfish`. (`gnome-search-tool` was already covered in a previous answer). Catfish is present in repos, so use Synaptic, or

```
sudo apt-get install catfish
```

That can be added to the context menu in the file manager as indicated in another answer in relation to `gnome-search-tool`.

With `gedit` as text editor:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/contractor/catfish_search.contract
```

Paste this:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Search Here
Description=Find files
MimeType=inode;
Exec=catfish --path=%f %U
```

Save and close text editor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, It worked on Elementary 5.1.4, I couldn't find gnome-search-tool on apt.

Answer (score 9):

I highly suggest you to try [Synapse launcher](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project).

It's basically an alternative application launcher that can search for files *as well as* applications. It just sits there in wingpanel and gets activated once you press the keyboard shortcut : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (which you can modify to be anything you want to). You can add and remove extensions so it searches for anything you like.

It comes pre-bundled with a couple of themes. Here's a screenshot of me typing the word `elementary` in it using one of the pre-bundled themes:

[image]

#### Installation instructions

Here's how to install Synapse in Elementary:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please edit your answer to add how to install synapse on eOS?

Comment: You're welcome! I already added the instructions in my answer.

Comment: Synapse looks great! Two questions: It does not provide a decent eOS design, does it? Are there any extra extensions that you recommend to install?

Comment: Even without the launcher you can install the package `synapse` (under 0.4 loki at least).

Answer (score 4):

If you, like me, prefer K-Find rather than Gnome Search Tool, then install K-Find through `sudo apt-get install kfind`, run `sudo nano /usr/share/contractor/find.contract` (see https://github.com/elementary/contractor for more info) and paste the following content:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Search here
Description=Find files here
MimeType=inode;application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=kfind %f
```

Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (letter 'O', not number '0') to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

To use K-Find, open the folder where you want to locate your file, right click any empty area of the window and click "Search here".

[image: K-Find]

Comment: Thank you! What makes it better in your opinion than the Gnome search tool?

Comment: You're welcome! Both are nice tools, and they have the same filters. However, when using Gnome Seach Tool, you must select the desired filters on a combo box and go adding filters as you want. With K-Find you have the same filters, but in a tabbed interface. I think it is more "organized" and easier to use. Or perhaps I just prefer K-Find because I've entered the Linux world with the KDE interface lol

Comment: KDE UI is nice.I think this is a Qt application