# Pantheon Files: Search results in window instead of drop-down list?

Tags: pantheon-files, search

When I search for a document or picture in Files I get a drop-down list of things that match the results.

[image]

The list goes away if I click and multiple files cannot be selected or otherwise manipulated. I want to view the results in a separate window as shown below:

[image]

so that I can delete a few of the selected or move them to another folder.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a valid question. In fact, it is not very clear what the expected behaviour is (for example, are you referring to a search within a specific folder or across different folders?). In any case, this sounds more like a feature request because Files search tool does not provide the function you are talking about.

Comment: so is there any other software available `gui`

Comment: you might want to give a look here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/101/graphical-interfaces-to-search-for-files

Comment: Should the screenshots here show a stock elementary system?

Comment: unfortunately no they are with the `arcs` theme applied on them. Should I change them? @BillO'Dwyer

Comment: @BillO'Dwyer that's a question for meta.

Comment: @RolandiXor Can you direct me to the meta site?

Comment: I'm going to vote this as a duplicate of [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers) since it is a feature request (bug report)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You may report a "wishlist"-priority bug to launchpad for pantheon-files so that a designer may consider adding this option, even though it is probably unlikely unless you can make a good point about usability.

After internal discussions we put a strong limit on the total number of search results, mainly because you are expected to refine your search terms if you get a too large number of results, instead of going through a big list.

There are programs dedicated to searching like the gnome-search-tool or recoll for full text search, if you wish to have a different representation of search results it may be best to try one of those.

Comment: I won't go into extended discussion, but it's better to give the user a static list of icons, that they can interact with. If, for example, you accidentally click on one of the results, it takes you to the result. This also means you can't interact with multiple results in *any* manner.

Answer (score 1):

For a search app with more features, use [Catfish](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/catfish).

[image]

You can look for it in the `Software Center` or install it via command line (ie: in `Terminal`) using:

```
sudo apt-get install catfish
```