# File search doesn't work in Loki

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, search, nautilus

When I use the search function in "Files" in Elementary OS Loki, it only finds files in the folder that I'm currently in. Any way to activate recursive search?

When I install the "Files" version that is in the App Center, there search works as expected, but in the built-in version that comes with Loki it does not.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. And why have you added the `nautilus` tag? Is that what is installed under "Files" name from Appcenter?

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/122/170

Answer (score 2):

Considering Pantheon Files ("File Manager" in Loki, not to be confused with Nautilus sometimes called "Files") the search tool it's a bit different and rather **limited** compared to those of Nautilus or Dolphin, or to specialized tools like Catfish or Gnome-Search - especially in the way it displays the results.

- Search in current directory takes place by just typing the search.
- Recursive search (current folder and sub-folders) takes place by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and then typing.

**Typing or clicking during search process will stop the search.** Take care **not to type or click during search process**. More [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/260/170).

The results are listed just as a drop-down list (and [not as a file manager window](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/122/170) or search-tool window) that also never contains more than [ten items](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/9539/170) and that goes away in a second if you click or focus away in any way. (So, the search is 'recursive' with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> but you only get ten results).

[image]

Comment: I think the rational is that it should be similar to a browser navigation bar dropdown rather than a Google search.  Usually it is possible to type a suitably specific search term to limit the hits.

Comment: A branch is in the pipeline that increases the number of hits shown, however.