# More than ten search-results in Pantheon Files?

Tags: pantheon-files, files, search

I have answered myself a few times here on how to search files with Pantheon Files ([here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9537/170) and [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/260/170)) but I  now realize that the drop-down list of search results has no more than ten items.

[image]

At the end there are three points that suggest more results are to be found but clicking that shows nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this limit of 10 is hard-coded in the software code of `pantheon-files` (`libwidgets/View/SearchResults.vala`, lines 59-61)

```
    const int MAX_RESULTS = 10;
    const int MAX_DEPTH = 5;
    const int DELAY_ADDING_RESULTS = 150;
```

You can even increase this number in order to display more results, but nevertheless the number of results displayed stays limited. You can change the number 10 after `MAX_RESULTS =` to the value wanted in the file and rebuild the package (`debuild -us -uc`).

So you still might want to file a feature request to implement a way of showing all results when you click on the "…", however.

Comment: There is a branch in the pipeline that increases the number of results shown and limits each category of results separately so that a lot of hits in one category does not hide hits in another category.

Comment: `You can even increase this number in order to display more results` : can you give an example on how exactly to increase the number of results? (let's say 20, 25, 30...).

Comment: `nevertheless the number of results displayed stays limited` : that shouldn't be a problem, as the number of files on a computer is also limited :). But 10 is more "limited" than 30 or 40

Comment: @JeremyWootten - that sounds right but I don't understand it ;)

Comment: @cipricus Post edited, basically you just change the number 10 to the number you want (I tested with 16 and 24: if you put more than 16, there might not be enough place to display the results, though).

Comment: @cipricus:  I think lemonslice is talking about getting the source code, editing it, recompiling and installing the custom version. This is not very easy unless you are familiar with such things. There isnt an option in the program as supplied.  If the branch I mentioned is accepted into Elementary then it will eventually be released as an update.