# How do I search files with pantheon-files

Tags: pantheon-files

I'm a newbie with Elementary. How do I do a file search with Files? (I don't see a search box like in other file managers). Thanks.

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/260/170

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate. The other question is about dedicated GUI search applications, rather than searching in Pantheon. I'd like to add an answer here, based on the answer linked by @cipricus in the comment above.

Comment: @waldyrious - I guess it was marked as a duplicate of the other precisely because the latter has an [answer (by myself)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/260/170) that stands exactly for this question here. Pantheon Files is a GUI to search for files too. - The way questions are marked a duplicate is not very logical in my view: a second question very different (logically) from a first one can be marked as duplicate if the first one has by chance an answer that works for th second.

Comment: @waldyrious - Being marked as  duplicate depends less on the questions themselves than on the answers, and a more specific question may finish as duplicate of a more general one, like in this case here. - Even worse, a general question may finish as duplicate of a more specific/limited one because of the answers of the latter.