# Is it possible to search directories in slingshot?

Tags: pantheon-files, slingshot, search

I have moved from MacOS to elementary OS. One thing I miss is the ability to search within directories.

Is it possible to do so, I don't seem to be finding anything when searching the web. The only thing I have found is [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/186/3116), but I would like to stick with Slingshot if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Slingshot does not search files or folders. It searches apps, actions, and settings