# How to replace file manager in elementary OS?

Tags: luna, pantheon-files, nautilus

It's no secret that the weakest link on Luna is the file manager. Regular crashes at work is a disaster.

I suspect that it could be replaced by Nautilus or other FM, but I don't know how to do it safely for system and maximally integrate to the Pantheon Shell.

Comment: I would have to agree with Gabriel. Your copy of Pantheon Files is _massively_ out of date, and I believe there has been a major re-write in that time. Nothing will carry as much integration as the official original, and I urge you to try Freya, with 0.3.1 in August-ish, if not now.

Comment: I'm using Freya and Pantheon-files is absolutely horrible if you have a folder with pictures in it in excess of 200. I have a folder with over 1000 images and it's so slow to scroll and access the photos to edit or move. It needs to be fixed big time...

Comment: Btw, question and best answer apply for Luna and Freya...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with your perception of Files, which I consider the best file manager around.

My recommendation would actually be to install Freya which comes with the *much* improved version of Files.

If you still want to install another file manager, it's as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install <your-choice>
```

Nothing bad will happen with any extra file manager you install as long as I am aware (and I've installed many just to try).

---

**ADD**

As igrossiter says (thank you for reminding me of this), if you install `Nemo` you might end up with an "un-closable" window in your desktop that you can't close (see [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111265810590904391682/posts/QfdoPoxDeDm)).

To fix this you need to add `--no-desktop` to the `nemo.desktop` file so it reads:

```
Exec=nemo --no-desktop %U
```

Comment: on freya I had some problems when trying to install nemo, nothing serious but it added a giant window floating that supposed to be the desktop. with thunar the icons got horrible, so I gave up and continued with files, my point is, it is not so easy to change it successfully

Comment: Thanks @igrossiter, I had forgotten about that issue. I added the fix to my answer but this is just more reason to stick with the wonderful `Files` IMO.

Comment: I tried to install Nautilus and Nemo, but I decided against them because they look disgusting.

Comment: @PNG Use Files for a while, you won't be disappointed.

Answer (score 3):

To replace file manager in freya:

Install other file manager, for example `nautilus`.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

To distinguish between Pantheon-files  and nautilus, and to show nautilus in applications launcher:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

In [desktop entry]:

Change `Name` and `OnlyShowIn` entries to

```
Name=Nautilus Files

OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;Pantheon;
```

You can easily modify file manager from GUI:

System settings --> applications --> default -->

[image: Imgur]

To identify the current file manager:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

See `man xdg-mime` for more info.

To set nautilus as default file manager:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search.
```

For [Nemo](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/remove-icons-from-desktop/1209#1209)