# Strange nested desktop, please help!

Tags: desktop

I have installed the LastPass app and got created a nested desktop, I cannot remove it in any way, please help!

[image: Desktop]

Comment: Sorry Guys, [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/remove-icons-from-desktop) was the issue: NEMO

Comment: If you were able to solve the problem, it would be helpful to answer your own question here in case someone else encounters the same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by  uninstalling `nautilus-nemo`.

```
sudo apt-get remove nemo
```

Reference [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1209/2708)