# How do I get rid of a "desktop inside of a desktop" bug?

Tags: release-loki, desktop

I'm new to eOS. Today I made my fresh install on my computer. I just installed latest release (Loki) and after a installing a few packages it happened this:

[image: What?]

As you can see, there is a desktop window inside desktop (?). The only issue here is I cant drag icons freely on desktop screen, icons are stuck inside that window. Among few things i did before, I just installed elementary-tweaks and some other programs (I was wondering if it has to do with installing Nemo fileroller. I can interact with this window and it opens directly that file manager when click on a folder). Anyone else with this issue? Any fix or workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record:

The command **nemo --no-desktop** seems to work on some configs, but not always. A bit of research and found that

```
 gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

did the trick for me ([link](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3083/nemo-launches-a-desktop-window-linux-mint-16-cinnamon.1.html)). As the problem is solved for me, I still wish to know if is possible to make nemo appear fullscreen. When installed on Ubuntu there is no issue with this window >:( (it is maybe configured correctly to work on some distros?)

Answer (score 2):

This worked with Luna, you can try and see if it still works (taken from [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/514/9)):

If you install Nemo you might end up with an "un-closable" window in your desktop that you can't close (see here).

To fix this you need to add --no-desktop to the `nemo.desktop` file so it reads:

```
Exec=nemo --no-desktop %U
```

Comment: Mmm... did that, saved nemo.desktop and reboot. Nothing changed. I'll be checking the answer you linked :)

Comment: Kind of get it, after reading a while of those threads I realized is because Nemo's behavior is not compatible with pantheon or something. Also, by default eOS desktop don't show icons. For the moment, only thing I do is to minimize the annoying window (right click > minimize). I wonder if instead of getting rid of that window, we keep it maximized, filling screen behind menus... which would be a workaround, I guess.