# How can I see the thumbnails of HEVC and mkv with VP9 encode videos?

Tags: pantheon-files, codec

As you can see in the picture below, only the H264 codec video shows up its thumbnail, not the HEVC or VP9 (mkv).

How do I see their thumbnails?

[image]

Comment: The vp9 video was downloaded by youtube-dl

Comment: youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvk1-5VDcNU

Comment: The thumbnail shows up after I change the ".mkv" to ".webm"

Comment: By the way, the youtube-dl has to be the latest version, the Ubuntu official version is way too old!

Comment: Please drop at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33570/ravan-and-julianlai

Answer (score 1):

*This may not be exact solution but a temporary work-around*. Working for `vp9`

If you want to have preview/thumbnails, use `nautilus`.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Recommended reading: [Is Nautilus really “not-recommended”?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/356/is-nautilus-really-not-recommended)

Install `totem` and `ffmpegthumbnailer`

```
sudo apt-get install totem ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Now the task is to keep only `totem.thumbnailer` in `/usr/share/thumbnailers/`. For this, open terminal and run:

```
sudo pantheon-files
```

Click on File system --> usr --> share --> thumbnailers -->

Here keep ONLY `totem.thumbnailer`, CUT remaining two and place in home folder (your choice).

Close files.

Now clear cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.thumbnails
mkdir ~/.thumbnails
```

Now launch `nautilus`