# How to enable desktop icons and right click in Elementary OS Freya?

Tags: desktop, user-interface, app-shortcuts

I cannot put any icons or right click on the desktop in Elementary Freya. How can I enable that?

Comment: By default the desktop in elementary OS is disable. Have you enabled it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the desktop

**Step 1:**
Install Nautilus dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nautilus dconf-tools
```

**Step 2:**
Open dconf-editor and go to,  `org` > `gnome` > `nautilus` > `desktop` and tick on any option which you want to view on desktop.
[image]

**Step 3:**
Then go to, `org` > `pantheon` > `desktop` > `cerbere` and add 'nautilus -n' entry as shown below.

```
['wingpanel', 'plank', 'slingshot-launcher --silent', 'nautilus -n']
```

[image]

**Step 4:**
Open Terminal and type following command, `nautilus -n`

**Step 5:**
Go to dconf-tools again and go to, `org` > `gnome` > `desktop` > `background` and tick on **show-desktop-icons box**
[image]

If there is any problem, simply logout and login again.

Comment: nice answer!, this seems to be a duplicate question, doesn't it? Please use flag :)

Comment: The other answer has link in it. This has more detailed answer so we can flag the new ones as duplicate and link it to this answer.

Comment: nope, see [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/21/2708), your answer is same as this one except screenshots.