# How to change Desktop icon font color?

Tags: desktop, icons

I have desktop enabled but the font color is black. How can I change the icon font color to white?

Answer (score 3):

If you enabled the desktop icons by Nautilus ([How to enable desktop icons and right click in Elementary OS Freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/how-to-enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-in-elementary-os-freya)), you can do the following:

1. `cd ~/.config/gtk-3.0`
2. `nano gtk.css`
3. add the css: `.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {color: #ffffff;text-shadow: 1 1 alpha (@fg_color, 0.8);}`
4. restart session

Change the color as you want.