# Right-click desktop Juno?

Tags: release-juno, desktop

How to enable right-click and icons on desktop for Juno?
Previous version guides doesn't work. Please,bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked previously. Try the solution provided here:

[How enable desktop icons on elementaryOS 5.0 Juno?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15915/how-enable-desktop-icons-on-elementaryos-5-0-juno)

Comment: A natively impossible? I know about the application, but I want it to work without it.

Comment: One of the developers explained why it's not done natively. You can read his response here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-cant-i-place-files-on-the-desktop-by-default-and-how-can-i-get-this-featur