# Folders etc. on desktop like on OsX?

Tags: desktop

I wanted to know if it is possible to have desktop experience with EOS, just like in OsX? Would greatly appreciate any help or information about that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

go to the app center, search & install the app: "desktop folder". that's it.

but maybe, after some time you will notice that there is no need for folders on the desktop, because everything can be attached to the dock and the rest can be accessed via apps (top left, also quickly accessible via hot corner or keyboard shortcuts).

i only have a note (also a feature of this app) on the desktop.

a desktop should keep space free resp. should be there to manage open applications. that's all. imho. but everybody as he wants.

ps: you can have your dock automatically fade in when you move the mouse to the bottom. maximized windows can still cover it if you don't do something like that (in this way, you can also minimize an open, maximized application to the dock itself; without any minimize - button).

pps: you can also configure the dock in any possible way:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9o-9uE6Iwg

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible ;) but very big BUT. What is the point to change ElementaryOS to look like and act like another OS or distribution, if you need desktop folders and icons try other distributions, or to be specified other Desktop Environments.

EDIT: And check [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/elementary-desktop-icons-files-app).

EDIT2: And with one simple search on the [elementaryos.stackexchange.com](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com) you will get [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15915/how-do-i-enable-desktop-icons-on-elementaryos-5-0-juno). ;)