# Can't find org>pantheon>desktop>cerbere on dconf

Tags: desktop, pantheon, icons, ubuntu

I've been trying to enable desktop icons on pantheon, however the desktop configurations on my pantheon don't appear to be working right. Any idea how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there is no easy way to enable desktop icons. I recommend do use "Desktop Folder" (https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.spheras.desktopfolder)

However, it seems to be possible to use nautilus to get the icons back on the desktop like described here: [How to enable desktop icons and right click in Elementary OS Freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/how-to-enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-in-elementary-os-freya)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+F and type `cerbere` location is `/io/elementary/desktop/cerbere`

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

"Desktop Folder" is in the AppCentre and it allows access to the desktop as I wanted, and is usual l with other distros.