# Close, minimize, and maximize button icon locations

Tags: icons

I want to change the appearance of those 3 buttons, but I'm not sure where they are located on elementaryOS.

I see people talk a lot about Elementary Tweaks, but I don't know much about it. I know Linux can be funny, so I don't want to install a repository that somehow messes up my OS. Also, I'm not sure if there are any backdoors in it or not.

That is why I just want to do this manually, if it is even possible.

Comment: Tweaks is fine to install via an added repository, but you can get the 3-button layouts using only the commandline without installing anything. These instructions should still work: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/how-can-i-get-a-minimize-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a "minimize" button?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/how-can-i-get-a-minimize-button)

Comment: I want to make those three buttons look like the ones on a Mac, so a red, yellow, and green circle.