# How do I put applications on the home screen?

Tags: plank, display, home

Someone said in a video that it's currently not supported but, is there a way to put applications on the home screen and not just the dock?

Thanks!

Trace

Comment: By the home screen, do you mean the desktop?

Comment: Yes! @RyanDeBeasi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this question and the first couple of answers](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-cant-i-place-files-on-the-desktop-by-default-and-how-can-i-get-this-featur). The short version is that it's not possible by default, and that's by design. Applications live in the "slingshot" menu in the top left.

That said, by [following these instructions](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/21/792), you can add this feature to Elementary.